# How to set cookies in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

I want to store username and password in cookies.If due to some reason my page removed when i will type the URL and press enter the page will come which should come after login.I have used also session.Please help me to add cookies in my app.

I am working on the below code.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def loginuser
        @users=User.authenticate(params[:users][:email], params[:users][:password])
        if @users
            session[:user_id]=@users.id
            flash[:notice]="login successfull"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member',:controller => 'homes'
        else
            flash[:notice]="could not Logged in"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'member', :controller => 'homes'
        end
    end
    def removeuser
        session[:user_id] = nil
        flash[:notice]="user logged out successfully"
        flash[:color]="valid"
        redirect_to :action => 'member', :controller => 'homes'
    end
end
```

Please help me to add cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you are using `session` object to maintain session details, in the same way use `cookies` object to set cookies.
Here:

```
cookies[:user_name] = "david"
# Cookies are read and written through ActionController#cookies.
```

Also follow this reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Example:

```
def loginuser
        @users=User.authenticate(params[:users][:email], params[:users][:password])
        if @users
            session[:user_id] = @users.id
            cookies[:user_id] = @users.id # setting cookies 
            flash[:notice]="login successfull"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member',:controller => 'homes'
        else
            flash[:notice]="could not Logged in"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'member', :controller => 'homes'
        end
    end
```